# Java Date has shifted hours after parsing

Tags: java

I have a rest service that takes date as a string and an adapter parses it to *java.util.date*:

```
 private static final String FORMAT_DATE = "dd.MM.yyyy";

 /*
  * Omitted.
  */

 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(FORMAT_DATE);
 sdf.setLenient(false);

 try {
     setTime(sdf.parse(stringRealizationDate).getTime());
     invalidDate = false;
 } catch (ParseException parseException) {
     invalidDate = true;
     LOG.error("Instantiation failed");
 }
```

The `stringRealizationDate` is: 23.02.2017 and after parsing it it becomes 22.02.2017 23:00. 
How to make it always be 23.02.2017 00:00 without any time zones aspects? It cannot be shifted under no circumstances.

Comment: How you detect that time is "22.02.2017 23:00"?

Comment: setTime(sdf.parse(stringRealizationDate).getTime()); after that the date is 22.02

Comment: I have tried `Date date = sdf.parse(stringRealizationDate)`, print it as `date.toString()` and it gives me output `Thu Feb 23 00:00:00 IST 2017`. Please check your setTime function.

Comment: If you want to keep the format same you can use format method of SimpleDateFromat.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot rely on parsing a String not explicitly containing timezone information without somehow defining the timezone.

The `SimpleDateFormat` internally uses a `Calendar` to store the parsing result. This calendar will be instantiated with system locale and therefore system timezone. Your `stringRealizationDate` will be treated as being passed with the context of system timezone which seems to be `+01:00`.

Now, `SimpleDateFormat.parse()` returns a `Date`. `Date` however is intended to store *UTC* values, so the `+01:00` timezone offset causes to have one hour being substracted during conversion to *UTC*.

One solution would be having the correct timezone (`+01:00`) set when using your `Date` so the calculation from *UTC* to `+01:00` would result in the correct value being e.g. printed on screen. But that is some kind of tricky to manage in larger applications.

Another solution would be using `SimpleDateFormat.setTimeZone()` before calling `parse()` to explicitly define the timezone the formatter should assume your input has (if not defined there explicitly). However, the problem with having a `Date`that always carries *UTC* timezone values is not solved at all.

The best solution would be using the new Time API which is available since Java8. There you have classes explicitly holding non-timezoned values, in your case [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html).

The interesting method there would be [LocalDate.parse(CharSequence text,
                              DateTimeFormatter formatter)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-) since it allows you to pass your input String and define your expected date format. **But be alert, you cannot convert a `LocalDate` to a [Unix timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) without passing a timezone (and making assumptions about the time parts of it) since it does not represent a point-in-time but a fragment of it, the date part.**